# PHP date() shows dd-MM-YY and my current timezone

Tags: php, date, timezone

I'm trying to display the date and clock in my col-md-3 with my current timezone (Asia/Makassar) and using 24 hour format.

```
<?php
    $dateToday = date("D, d M Y H:i:s");
    echo $dateToday;
?>
```

This is what I expected:

```
Sat, 2 Jan 2016 10:16:02
```

Comment: You forgot quotes around your parameter to date()

Comment: Careful. Do you want to display the server's time or the user's time? PHP will display the server's time, which will be "wrong" for the user if they are in a different time zone.

Comment: *"This is what i expected"* - and what is it exactly did you get back? ;-) [Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'M' (T_STRING)?](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) - *Yep*

Comment: So what is your timezone set to in php.ini?

Comment: When learning PHP, **always** refer to the official manuals on the [PHP.net](http://php.net) website ***first***. http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php `string date ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )` http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: yeah but the matter is how to sync my page clock with specific time zone, because it has +12 hours difference

Answer (score 1):

You must pass a string to the date object:

```
$dateToday=date("D, d M Y H:i:s");
```

Also note that PHP will show the date according to the timezone of the server, not the client. You can override this to a different timezone if you would like:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php